# Disable AMD graphic card to save battery

Tags: drivers, ati, battery, intel

I just bought a dell inspiron 5537 (which already comes with ubuntu 12) and I removed the ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside a windows 8.1.

After struggling with [the system is running low on graphics error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) I got it fixed by installing AMD Radeon HD driver. However I noticed that before (when I had the Ubuntu 12 that came with the device) the battery life was up to 6 hours and now it's no longer than 4 hours. So now I think I should disable the AMD card (since the built-in intel HD card will work fine on Ubuntu), maybe that will extend the battery's life?

But, is there a trusted way to do that without returning to the low graphic mode?

Answer (score 1):

base on your description, you have the proprietary driver installed.

You could switch between AMD / Intel GPU by using the AMD Catalyst Control Center

This could be done by searching AMD in your dash
[image: Search AMD in dash]
And open the "Administrative" one to switch GPU. You will be asked to enter your password for it.
[image: Enter password for administrative mode]

However, currently there is a bug affecting it: https://pad.lv/1309550

If nothing happened after you entered the password. Please open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and run:

`sudo amdcccle`

You will see this control center, and switch the desired GPU here:
[image: control center]

Comment: After doing this I'm not able to open Catalyst again and also my `unity-control-center` stopped to work

Comment: @DougCorrea That sounds like a bug to me. I would suggest you to give the latest AMD fglrx from AMD (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) a try. If it still persists, open a bug report will be a wonderful step.