# Ubuntu on Laptop with switchable Graphics Card (AMD)

Tags: ati

After I got problems with Windows again, i switched to Ubuntu on my old Laptop (Acer Aspire 7750G). Im very happy with Ubuntu and how user friendly and light it is. I mainly use it to browse the web or watch videos on YouTube or Netflix and casually play on it. Here's the thing. I liked to play CS:GO with my friends, but I cant get my AMD graphics card to work (Game uses onboard IntelHD 3000). My question is, how do I install/utilize my graphics card(AMD Radeon HD 7670M) because all the tutorials/links on google are for older Versions and now on the AMD site there are so many packages, where I don't now which one to chose. Please help me :/
English isn't my native language, so sorry for any grammatical mistake.

Comment: Tutorials for older versions of Ubuntu usually work fine. To get the official AMD drivers you can open the `Additional Drivers` program and install them from there. To make sure you don't use the Intel card, you might have to disable it in the BIOS.

Comment: Check this article for driver installation [How do I install additional drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers), and this article for switchable graphics [Disable AMD graphic card to save battery](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525108/disable-amd-graphic-card-to-save-battery/525127#525127)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will not automatically choose the VGA for you, you should do it manually.

first, install AMD Catalyst by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

After that, reboot your computer. Then you can access the `aticonfig` command. First, it needs to be initialized:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

reboot your PC again, then Run AMD Catalyst Control Centre and you will have the option of switchable graphics like Windows.

EDIT: it's always the best practice to install additional drivers using GUI because you can see if the driver is compatible with your system before actually installing it. Using the command line will install the driver anyway, it does not look if your hardware supports the driver or not.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
After the installation and the reboot, i tried the command 'sudo aticonfig --initian' but it says " no supported adapters found" ....

Comment: if the answer helped you, you can mark it as correct so others can benefit from it as well @HuyTaoDuc

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal think it's better to encourage people to install proprietary drivers form the GUI (the "Additional Drivers" tool), so that you could know if the card is supported and detected correctly. By using the command line command, people can just install that package anyway.